# Internet Explorer Inspect mode

Tags: internet-explorer

I need help getting out of performance mode, I was just exploring and it took me this other window which disable all the functionality to revert back to console, network and memory tabs. Looks like this. Note: I am using virtubox
Please help me get out of this mode Performance mode. I had to press CTRL + E to initiate it need assistance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoiBz.png) getting out of it.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post pictures of code, or pictures of error messages, or pictures of logs, or generally pictures of any kind of text. Text in pictures cannot be searched, text in pictures cannot be copypasted into an IDE, text in pictures cannot be copypasted into a web search engine, and text in pictures cannot be read by blind or otherwise visually impaired people. Just copy the text and paste it into your question as text. If you are unsure how to format it properly, don't worry, we can help with that.

Comment: What do you mean performance mode? Do you mean the Performance tab in F12 dev tools? Could you please provide the steps to reproduce the issue? The image you provide doesn't look like the interface of performance tab. Does rebooting IE work? If it doesn't work, you could refer to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318378/how-to-repair-or-reinstall-internet-explorer-in-windows) to reinstall or repair IE.